# How to print all assertion failure messages into HTML report of SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am running test case and asserting data using groovy. I want to print each and every failed message to `html junit generate report`.

**Example Code**

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

    def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
    def jsonString = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

    assert !(jsonString.isEmpty())
    assert jsonString.code == 200
    assert jsonString.status == "success"

    def accountInfo = jsonString.data
    assert !(accountInfo.isEmpty())

    def inc=0

    //CHECKING LANGUAGES IN RESPONSE
    if(accountInfo.languages.id!=null)
    {

           log.info("Language added successfully")
    }
    else
    {

         log.info("Language NOT added.") //want to display this in html report
         inc++

    }

    if(accountInfo.educations!=null)
      {

       log.info("Educations added successfully")
      }
    else
     {

     log.info("Educations NOT added.") //want to display this in html report
     inc++

     } 

assert inc<=0,"API unable to return all parameters, Please check logs"
```

**Scenario**

What I am doing here is , IF test condition does not match and go to **ELSE**, I do increment of variable **inc** by 1. So at the end if fail my test if inc>0.

**Report**

In junit style html generated report, if test failed it display only one message called `API unable to return all parameters, Please check logs`

But what I want is to display each **IF** condition message into HTML report if for any condition goes into **ELSE** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of pointers:

- assert stops at first failure and only this failure message is part of junit report.
- having said that, user will not know if there are any further verification failures for the current response.
- the messages that are part of `if..else` are not part of `junit report`
- in order to achieve that, need to collect all those messages and finally show the collected error messages.
- below solution uses a variable, `messages` and appends each failure which allows to show them at the end. this way all failures can be shown in the report if that is desirable which OP requested for.
- user can also show the messages in the report using below statement apart from `assert` statement

  `if (messages) throw new Error(messages.toString())`

**Script Assertion**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


//check if the response is empty
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def jsonString = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def messages = new StringBuffer()
jsonString.code == 200 ?: messages.append("Code does not match: actual[${jsonString.code}], expected[200]\n")
jsonString.status == "success" ?: messages.append("Status does not match: actual[${jsonString.status}], expected[success]\n")

def accountInfo = jsonString.data
accountInfo ?: messages.append('AccountInfo is empty or null\n')

def inc=0

//CHECKING LANGUAGES IN RESPONSE
if(accountInfo.languages.id) {
   log.info('Language added successfully')
} else {
    log.error('Language NOT added.') //want to display this in html report
    messages.append('Language not added.\n')
    inc++
}

if(accountInfo.educations) {
    log.info('Educations added successfully')
} else {
    log.error('Educations NOT added.') //want to display this in html report
    messages.append('Educations NOT added.\n')
    inc++
} 

//inc<=0 ?: messages.append('API unable to return all parameters, Please check logs.')
//if(messages.toString()) throw new Error(messages.toString())
assert inc<=0, messages.append('API unable to return all parameters, Please check logs.').toString()
```

Comment: Your given solution works fine for me. Just one issue it is not failing my test case even if assertion failed. Until assertion everything works fine. But when I look at junit html report. It shows status = pass. What I want is report should get fail when assertion get fail and print all assertion message in report to see which failed.

Comment: Have you used as it is? Has it shown all the messages that you intended? Have you managed to try it from withing SoapUI itself?

Comment: Just changed `if (messages)` to `if (messages.toString())` in the answer. Can you please try this updated answer?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138292/room-for-rao-and-helping-hands